# TableView To represent details from search

Tags: ios6, uitableview, xcode5

I am really new to Xcode iOS development.

I am implementing search with "auto-complete".(Asynchronously sending request to the server for each letter user has inserted and by this connection, I am fetching requested data from the server).
this part works pretty fine :)

My issue is to represent the search result in the table view , I googled a lot
but I couldn't find any good example that would help me.
when the tableView draws for first time everything is fine , but when I fetch another request:
(once the second key is pressed the request returns new data and i want to draw it in the table,without the previous data).

My application crashes with the exception "incorrect selector sent to instance 0x..."

I am storing the fetched data in NSArray *FetchedData;
afterwards I changed:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
     return [FetchedData count];
}
```

And in other function (I think I have to change something here but I don't know what).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


cell.cellName.text = (NSString*)[FetchedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

After I getting the FetchedData I call the function:
      [self.tableView reloadData];

but in the function above I am crashing after I trying to represent the next fetched data 
that is different from the previous (it can even be empty)

I think I might need to delete all the previous cells, 
but I don't know how to do so .(I tried some codes from google and from this site ,but I lack basic knowledge,I keep getting all the possible exceptions).

Please can some one give me a decent example with basic explanations ?I would very much appreciate it

Thanks.

Comment: more details on "incorrect selector sent to instance 0x...", what is the selector and which object is it sent to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your tableViewCell class somewhere (viewDidLoad),

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[CustomTableViewCellClass class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellResuseIdentifier"];
```

and then in,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
CustomTableViewCellClass *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellReuseIdentifier"];

cell.cellName.text = (NSString*)[FetchedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

After you have fetched your data, call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: What is NIB ? I am not using interface builder , and why should I register the Custom tableView?.
I am inside tableViewController , it isn't good enough ?
and I did the reloadData function as well.

Comment: Even if you are not using interface builder, you need to register the class with a reuse identifier, table view works with that identifier to return a cell that is not visible on screen to improve performance. For reloading data, sending reloadData to your table view works like charm.

Comment: Oh so "reuseindetifier" should do the trick ?

Could you make an example for me how do I register without the interface builder?